# How do I get PhantomJS the Javascript heap size for a page?

Tags: javascript, performance, node.js, phantomjs

I'd like to get the Javascript heap size for a given page to before, during, and after Javascript functionality has been executed.

I looked at the PhantomJS docs (https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference), but I did not see methods to get the heap size.